# Problema al imprimir una matriz autogenerada

Tags: c++

Tengo que escribir en un fichero llamado matriz.txt una matriz de 7x7 formada por números con dos decimales. Llamo `i` al número de columnas y `k` al número de filas.

La matriz tiene que cumplir las siguientes condiciones:

- La primera y ultima columna (i[0], i[6]) tienen que ser 0.00
- La primera fila k[0] (obviando las columnas i[0], i[6]) tiene que cumplir la ecuacion x(i,0)=pi * i
- La segunda fila k[1] (obviando las columnas i[0], i[6]) debe cumplir `x(i,1) = 2*x(i,0)+3x(i+1,0)`
- Las demás filas deben cumplir `x(i,k) = 2*x(i,k-2)+5*x(i+1,k-1)`

He hecho esto pero no imprime nada, solo la primera fila:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    const double pi = 3.14159;
    double matriz[7][7];

    //columna 1 y 7
    for(unsigned k = 0; k<7 ; k++){
        matriz[k][0] = 0.00 ;
        matriz[k][6] = 0.00 ;
    }
    //fila 1
    for(unsigned i = 0; i<6 ; i++){
        matriz[0][i] = pi*i;
        std::cout << matriz[0][i] << "\t" << std::endl;
    }
    //fila 2
    for (int i = 1; i< 6 ; i++){
        matriz[1][i] = 2*matriz[0][i]+3*matriz[0][i+1];
    }
    //Resto de filas
    for(int k = 2; k < 7; k++){
        for (int i =1; i < 6; i++){
            matriz[k][i] = 2  * matriz[k-2][i] + 5 * matriz[k-1][i+1];
        }
    }   
    std::cout << matriz << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Hola Juan, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. No te olvides de completar el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general, y así ganarás tu primera medalla.

Comment: Tienes un poco de lío con los índices de los arrays en los bucles. Si la primera columna y la última de cada fila tiene que quedarse a cero, en los `for` tendrías que ir de `1` hasta `6` no de `0` hasta `7` como haces en la primera fila, ni de `1` hasta `10` que haces en la segunda (solo tienes 7), ni de `2` hasta `11` en el tercer `for` para el resto de filas. Salvo ese, la primera y segunda fila serían de `1` a `6`. Y el resto de filas desde `k = 2` hasta `7` y el interno desde `i= 1` hasta `6`. Y para imprimir la matriz, tienes la respuesta ya publicada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para imprimir la matriz, debes recorrerla:

```
for( int j=0;j<7; j++){ -> filas
  for(int i=0; i<7; i++){ -> columnas
    std::cout << arr[j][i] << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n'; -> Salto de linea despues de cada fila
}
```

Para imprimir la matriz en un fichero:

```
ofstream fichero;
fichero.open ("Rutadetufichero");

if ( fichero ){ //--> Comprueba que se abre el fichero correctamente.
  for( int j=0; j<7; j++){// -> filas 
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){ // -> columnas
      fichero << arr[j][i] << ' ';
    } 
    fichero << '\n'; //-> Salto de linea despues de cada fila 
  }
  fichero.close();
}
else{
   std::cout << "error al abrir el fichero";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya he conseguido que imprima la matriz por consola pero como puedo imprimirla en un fichero (matriz.txt)?

Comment: Para imprimirla en un fichero:  include <fstream> ofstream fichero; fichero.open ("Rutadetufichero"); for( int j=0;j<7; j++){ -> filas for(int i=0; i<7; i++){ -> columnas fichero << arr[j][i] << ' ' } fichero << '\n'; -> Salto de linea despues de cada fila } ; fichero.close()

Comment: He puesto eso, crea el fichero pero esta vacio... std::ofstream Fichero("matriz.txt", std::ios::out);
 Fichero.open("matriz.txt");
 for( int k=0;k<7; k++){ //-> filas 
  for(int i=0; i<7; i++){ //-> columnas 
   Fichero << matriz[k][i] << ' '; 
   } 
  Fichero << '\n'; //-> Salto de linea despues de cada fila 
  }  
 Fichero.close();
}

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta, para que lo veas mas claro.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes imprimir la matriz enviándola a un flujo de salida de datos, por ejemplo a consola:

```
for (const auto &fila : matriz)
{
    for (const auto &valor : fila)
        std::cout << valor << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Si quieres que se imprima en un archivo, haz que el flujo de salida sea a archivo:

```
if (std::ofstream archivo{"archivo.txt"})
{
    for (const auto &fila : matriz)
    {
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
            archivo << valor << ' ';
        archivo << '\n';
    }
}
```